# Birthday block in Drupal without deceased and deleted contacts

Tags: drupal

I found a piece of code to show a birthday block in Drupal.
Had to modify it a little bit to get it to work with the current versions.
But I noticed that deleted or deceased persons were still showing up in this list.
I don't know the correct code for this. Could someone please fix this code for me and others that are wanting to use this code?
My php / mysql skills are not enough but I think it must be something like:      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `civicrm_contact` \n"
        . "where `is_deceased` = false";

```
    <?php
// Check if CiviCRM is installed here.
if (!module_exists('civicrm')) return false;

// Initialization call is required to use CiviCRM APIs.
civicrm_initialize(true);
require_once('CRM/Core/DAO.php');

$query = "SELECT id, display_name, birth_date, CONCAT(((RIGHT(birth_date,5)
< RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)) + YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)), RIGHT(birth_date,6)) AS bday,
concat(concat(month(birth_date), '/'), day(birth_date)) as displaydate, 
(TO_DAYS(CONCAT(((RIGHT(birth_date,5) < RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)) + YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)),
RIGHT(birth_date,6))) - TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE)) AS toBday FROM civicrm_contact WHERE
(TO_DAYS(CONCAT(((RIGHT(birth_date,5) < RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)) + YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)),
RIGHT(birth_date,6))) - TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) < 7) ORDER BY bday, RIGHT(birth_date,5);";

$params = array( );

$dao =& CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery( $query, $params );

echo "<div class=\"item-list\"><ul>\n";
while ( $dao->fetch( ) ) {

echo "<li><a href=\"/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=" . $dao->id . "\">" . $dao->display_name .
"</a>, " . $dao->displaydate;

echo "</li>\n";

}
echo "</div></ul>\n";

?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using PHP rather than creating a block with Views?

Comment: i suspect because of the difficulty in getting anyone whose birthday is in Month x ie regardless of the year. Various workarounds have been suggested in drupal including using php in Views so perhaps the above is a 'tidy' solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query (the only difference being the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT id, display_name, birth_date, CONCAT(((RIGHT(birth_date,5)
< RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)) + YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)), RIGHT(birth_date,6)) AS bday,
concat(concat(month(birth_date), '/'), day(birth_date)) as displaydate, 
(TO_DAYS(CONCAT(((RIGHT(birth_date,5) < RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)) + YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)),
RIGHT(birth_date,6))) - TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE)) AS toBday FROM civicrm_contact WHERE
(TO_DAYS(CONCAT(((RIGHT(birth_date,5) < RIGHT(CURRENT_DATE,5)) + YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)),
RIGHT(birth_date,6))) - TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) < 7) AND is_deceased = 0 AND is_deleted = 0 ORDER BY bday, RIGHT(birth_date,5);
```

Comment: Thx Jon. Will try this later today.

Comment: That worked. I made some small changes to fit my needs considering date and name formats.